# Proxy squid Very slow

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I work in a school where we have approximately 500 computers. We have installed a proxy SQUID  to filter adult websites etc. The server got like 32go ram and enough storage. But surfing become too slow when there are too many clients.
-What could be the reason?
-Is One proxy server is not enough for 500 clients?

Squid.conf:

```
# /etc/squid/squid.conf


acl localnet src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128

cache_mem 20480 MB

cache_dir aufs /dev/partage 200000 16 256
cache_dir aufs /dev/data 200000 16 256
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
cache_store_log /var/log/squid/store.log
logfile_rotate 10

dns_nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
dns_v4_first on
positive_dns_ttl 12 hours
negative_dns_ttl 1 minutes

fqdncache_size 4096
#maximum_object_size 4 MB
minimum_object_size 0 KB
maximum_object_size 96 MB

memory_cache_mode always
memory_replacement_policy lru


acl srv_interne dst xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

cache deny srv_interne

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320


url_rewrite_program /usr/bin/squidGuard
url_rewrite_children 8


max_filedesc 4096
```

Comment: There is no way to know without seeing the configuration and some information about the resource usage.

Comment: Please edit the additional information directly into the question. And please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste, that just makes it harder to extract relevant information.

Comment: Done, Sorry  I'm new to the forum.

Comment: 8 thread's could be to less for such a amount. have you enough bandwidth?

Comment: Yes 2 ISP with fiber

Comment: Are you talking about "url_rewrite_children"? How much I have to put  for 500 clients?